# .NET Linq Left Join

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

I have 2 tables in SQL:

```
Table 1 
Step Id
Step Name

Table 2
Profile Id
Step Id
Completed
```

I would like to return the following results even if there is not match in table 2:

```
Results
Table1.Step Id
Table1.Step Name
Table2.Profile Id
Table2.Completed
```

The way I am doing this in SQL is the following:

```
select * from [Table 1] t1
left join [Table 2] t2
on t1.Step Id = t2.Step Id
```

This produces the results I expect.

When I translate this into linq:

```
public static List<UserCompletion> GetStepCompletion(string category, string profileid) { 

List<Step> step = GetSteps(category);
List<UserStep> userStep = GetUserSteps(category, profileId);    

var q = from s in step
         join us in userStep
         on s.Id equals us.StepId
         select new UserCompletion
         {
           StepId = s.Id,
           Headline = s.StepName,
           ProfileId = us.ProfileId
           Completed= us.Completed
          };

     return q.ToList();

}
```

It works but like a `JOIN` not a `left join`. I only get matching results back.

Also, `UserCompletion` is an object that I return from this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try this (assuming us.Completed is boolean):

```
var q = from s in step
         let us = (from i in userStep where s.Id = i.StepId).SingleOrDefault()
         select new UserCompletion
         {
           StepId = s.Id,
           Headline = s.StepName,
           ProfileId = us.ProfileId
           Completed = us == null ? false : us.Completed
          };
```

This won't turn into a join in sql, but a nested select statement something like this:

```
select 
    StepId, Headline, ProfileId,
    isnull((select top(1) Completed from userStep where StepId = Id), 0) as Completed
from step
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something along the lines of the following:

```
var q = from s in step
        join us in userStep 
        on s.Id equals us.StepId into tmpjoin
        from x in tmpjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new UserCompletion { ... }
```

Comment: Nicely done. I was wimbling around trying to get syntax right :)

Comment: I tried that but i am getting a nullreference excpetion on the select line. - code below

var q = from s in step join us in userStep on s.Id equals us.StepId into tmpjoin from x in tmpjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new UserStepAccepted {StepId = s.Id, Headline = s.StepName, Completed= x.Completed};

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

Seems like I need to add a evaluation on the item that "may" be null.

I added the following to my select

```
Completed = (x == null) ? String.Empty : x.Completed
```